# respuesta json inesperado php

Tags: php, json

estoy haciendo una consulta en php y el resultado de esa consulta lo convierto en un `json` para despues enviarlo a `javascript`,pero al revisar el archivo en el que almaceno el json me di cuenta que el json tiene datos "duplicados"

json resultante:

```
{"0":"102452","ID":"102452","1":"26.777","T1":"26.777","2":"2020-07-21 13:50:02","FECHA":"2020-07-21 13:50:02"}
```

pero yo espero un json de esta forma:

```
{"ID":"102452","T1":"26.777","FECHA":"2020-07-21 13:50:02"}
```

alguien sabe en que me puedo estar equivocando,adjunto un fragmento del codigo de php,desde ya muchas gracias

codigo php:

```
$transmisores = '';
        if(count($checkboxes) == 1) {
        $transmisores = ' , ' . $checkboxes[0];
        } elseif(count($checkboxes) > 1) {
        $transmisores = ' , ' . implode(' , ',$checkboxes) . '';

        }
      
        $consulta="SELECT ID $transmisores,FECHA FROM datos_de_temperatura WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '$inicio $hr_inicio'AND '$fin $hr_fin'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        echo ($consulta);
        $json_array=array();
        if ($resultado){
           
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
            {
               
                $json_array[]=$row;
              
            }
```

Comment: me funciono perfecto,muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta!!!

Comment: O puedes usar directamente [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La API `mysqli` tiene varios métodos de lectura de datos (son los que empiezan por `fetch_`). Los más usados son:

- [**`mysqli_fetch_array()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), que organiza los datos **como un array numérico y asociativo al mismo tiempo**. Por ese motivo ves que en tu JSON los datos de cada columna se repiten como array numérico, por ejemplo: `"0":"102452"` y también como array asociativo: `"ID":"102452"`
- [**`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), que organiza los datos **como un array asociativo solamente**, algo así: `"ID":"102452", "T1":"26.777", ... etc`
- [**`mysqli_fetch_row()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), que organiza los datos **como un array numérico solamente**, algo así: `"0":"102452", "1":"26.777", ... etc`

Cada método existe para facilitar el consumo final de los resultados. Por tanto, según la necesidad puedes usar **el método más específico**. Queda claro que si te interesa una salida así:

```
{"ID":"102452","T1":"26.777","FECHA":"2020-07-21 13:50:02"}
```

el método específico a usar sería `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

```
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
        {
            $json_array[]=$row;
        }
```

Es importante conocer la forma en que cada método organiza los datos, para que uses siempre el método más adecuado.

El tipo de resultado también se puede indicar pasando una constante como segundo parámetro (opcional)  a `fetch_array`, [como bien dice el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> **resulttype**
>
> Este parámetro opcional es una constante que indica qué tipo de array debiera generarse con la información de la fila actual.
> Los valores posibles para este parámetro son las constantes
> `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, o `MYSQLI_BOTH`.
>
> Al emplear la constante `MYSQLI_ASSOC` esta función se comportará de
> manera idéntica a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, mientras que con
> `MYSQLI_NUM` se comportará exactamente igual que la función
> `mysqli_fetch_row()`. La última opción `MYSQLI_BOTH` creará un único
> array con los atributos de ambas dos.

O sea que podrías también hacerlo así:

```
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $json_array[]=$row;
        }
```